# Are river fish considered "seafood"

Tags: meaning, nouns

I am confused whether river fish can be categorised under "seafood".

Comment: I’d categorize them under ***fish***.  “Seafood” is really there so it can include things like shrimp, clams, and other edible non-fish from the ocean.

Comment: Hi Tejesh, welcome to EL&U. What did you find when you looked up *seafood* [NB: one word] in a dictionary? Can a *river* be considered part of the sea? Since the answer is readily found using commonly accessible resources, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. PS most would use the mass noun *fish* instead of the countable noun *fishes* in the given context. Also, you might find our other site [ell.se] has some useful resources. :-)

Comment: Interesting factoid: During Prohibition a restaurant with a seafood sign was signalling that you could get beer or liquor there. I remember reading that that was the case in Philadelphia. Here is a passage describing the same situation in Baltimore. https://books.google.de/books?id=ukjBjFN3JGoC&pg=PA36&dq=seafood+%22during+Prohibition%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-kpzzxYbiAhXNKewKHbGsD1IQ6AEIQDAF

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to EL&U. You are not the only person who is confused, looking around the internet there are a number of *different* definitions of 'seafood', even sources which can normally be considered reliable differ on this point.

For instance the [Online Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/seafood) defines seafood as:

> Shellfish and sea fish, served as food

which would *include* freshwater shellfish like freshwater clams and mussels, *include* sea fish like herring, tuna and cod but *exclude* freshwater fish like trout.

The [Collins online dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/seafood) on the other hand defines it as

> shellfish such as lobsters, mussels, and crabs, and sometimes other sea creatures that you can eat

This *excludes* all freshwater creatures and says that fin fish are only included sometimes.

also [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seafood) says it is

> edible marine fish and shellfish

which *includes* sea fin fish but is not clear as to whether freshwater shellfish are included.

On the other hand [Britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/topic/seafood) says it is

> edible aquatic animals, excluding mammals, but including both freshwater and ocean creatures

which definitely *includes* shellfish *and* fin fish from both salt water *and* fresh water. By the Britannica definition lobster, herring, freshwater clams, marine clams, cockles, prawns, trout, salmon and a whole host of other creatures are *included* and only mammals, birds and land dwelling creatures are *excluded*.

The [California Department of Public Health](https://www.cdph.ca.gov/Programs/CEH/DFDCS/Pages/FDBPrograms/FoodSafetyProgram/SeafoodAndShellfishSafety.aspx) defines shellfish as

> seafood products, which include all fish and fishery products intended for human consumption

it then goes on to list all sorts of creatures, both freshwater and saltwater and including frogs an alligators as seafood!

Interestingly [this cookery website](https://www.cooksinfo.com/seafood/) compares various definitions including a very broad one from the US Department of Agriculture and a much narrower one from the [Larousse Gastronomique](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larousse_Gastronomique). The discussion is worth reading but is far to long to copy here. However it ends with what I consider a very good summary of the argument from a cookery point of view which is

> Generally, if someone sits down in a restaurant and orders a Seafood Antipasto, or a Seafood Salad, they are not expecting to see a hunk of salmon on it: they are expecting calamari, scallop, shrimp, shellfish, etc.

Unfortinately, when it comes to 'seafood' there does not seem to be a universal definition or any agreement as to whether fin fish of any kind or freshwater shellfish are included or not. It seems that many organisations use definitions that suit their own purposes.

Comment: I'm not sure why you refer to "scaled" fish and therefore exclude fish without visible scales, e.g. swordfish, shark. Also, I don't think there's any ambiguity regarding freshwater fish: the definitions in MW, Oxford, Collins, Cambridge and Dictionary.com **all** specify fish *from the sea* (i.e. not freshwater fish). The only ambiguity is about non-fish aquatic animals, but that's not what the question asked about.

Comment: @chappo, Quite right, I should have said "fin fish", I'll change it. However some of the definitions I have seen, including those given by Britannica and CDPH, neither of which is trivial, specifically _include_ freshwater fin fish. I also suspect that the OP may well have meant shellfish and crustaceans as well as fin fish by the term "fish" since his confusion seems to stem from the inclusion of creatures from rivers in the term 'seafood'.

Comment: Isn't "fin fish" a tautology? What fish species doesn't have fins?

Comment: @Chappo Shellfish, crayfish, and jellyfish. :)

Comment: @tchrist Other invertebrates include starfish, cuttlefish and silverfish, though the latter infest my bookshelves rather than the oceans. Not to forget the oafish, elfish, offish, raffish and selfish, none of which are regarded as kosher/halal.

Comment: @Chappo I didn't have 'fin fish' in my vocabulary until I started looking at this question, which is why I used 'scaled fish'. I only found 'fin fish' used as a catch-all phrase for 'vertebrate aquatic creatures excluding mammals, birds, reptiles and amphibians' in some of the definitions. When you objected to 'scaled fish' I adopted the generally accepted term.

Answer (score 1):

It might be interesting to note that "sea-food" is predominantly an Amercian word. The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/174165) lists a quote from Baugh's 1935 history of the English language that reflects this:

> A writer in the London Daily Mail recently complained that an Englishman would find ‘positively incomprehensible’ the American words..*sea-food*,..and *hired-girl*.

The oldest citation in the OED is from 1836, but Google Ngram Viewer shows that the term "sea-food" has become more prevalent only since the 1940s:

[image]

Another citation from the OED illustrates this rise in the use of the term in the mid 20th century:

> Twenty or thirty years ago..fish was upgraded to seafood. (K. Hudson, *Jargon of Professions*, 1978)

So maybe "sea-food" is as ill defined as @BoldBen has expounded in their answer because **it is not the term used to speak of fish, shellfish, and such by most native English speakers**.

Here's another quote from the OED for your delectation:

> ‘I hope you like sea-food.’.. ‘Sea-food?.. Fish, that is? Oh yes, I do, indeed.’ (..True enough, though this ‘sea-food’ set Charles thinking that he also enjoyed ‘land~food’.) (J. Hilton, *Time & Time Again*, 1953)

Comment: Although I ended up sure that there was no universally agreed definition of 'seafood' I, personally, tend to think of it as being a translation of 'fruits de mer', 'meersfruchten' or fruitti di mare' and, therefore, excluding both freshwater invertebrates and all fin fish (although the [german definition of 'meersfruchten'](https://www.lebensmittellexikon.de/m0000540.php) specifically says that 'seafood' is a wider definition. I do wonder whether the wider definition(s) of 'seafood' came about because because of the greater distance of the inland States from the sea.